# What does it mean when the k value for SelectKBest is missing?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a modeling pipeline of which SelectKBest is a stage. Normally, if I want to access this SelectKBest stage from the pipeline after fitting(say, by using pipeline[2] if SelectKBest is the 3rd stage of the pipeline), it will return something like "SelectKBest(k=12)"

There are some instances, however, where SelectKBest will come back as "SelectKBest()" with no "k=..." in the parentheses.  Everything is seemingly ok with the pipeline; it produces predictions just fine.

So what, then, does it mean when no k= value is returned? Does this mean that SelectKBest has decided to use ALL features, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in 0.23, by default printing an estimator will only show parameters that are different than their default ([changelog](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.23.html#id13)).  So if you don't see `k=...` printed, it means [the default](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) of `k=10` is being used.